# How to pass the C pointers in swift

Tags: ios, c, swift, pointers

I am using C pointer in objective C

This is my C function:

```
long ListReaders(
__out char** szReadersList,
__out unsigned long* pulListLen){
}

long Result;   
char* pszReadersList;  
unsigned long pulListLen;  
Result=ListReaders(&pszReadersList, & pulListLen);
```

It is very easy to use the pointers in Objective C, but when i tried in swift there other concepts for pointers like `UnsafeMutablePointer`, `UnsafePointer` etc.

How can i use the same C function in swift

I tried to use it is showing like this

```
var Result :CLong?  
var pszReadersList :CChar?  
var pulListLen: CUnsignedLong?  
Result=ListReaders(szReadersList:UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>!UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>!>, pulListLen: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt>!UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt>!>)
```

Can you Guys please suggest me the usage of C pointers in swift

Comment: Can you show what `ListReaders` does, to see if it does make sense to use `CChar` and pointers?

Comment: What version of Swift?

Answer (score 3):

The code to call your C-function should be like this:

```
    var result: CLong = 0
    var pszReadersList: UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>? = nil
    var pulListLen: CUnsignedLong = 0
    result = ListReaders(&pszReadersList, &pulListLen)
```

---

Some points:

- In C/Objective-C, there are no primitive-Optionals, so you should not use them when working with C/Objective-C functions in Swift.

  `CLong?` -> `CLong`, `CUnsignedLong?` -> `CUnsignedLong`

  You may get some errors when you declare some variables of non-Optional primitive types, in such cases, do not use Optionals but just give them initial values.
- When you need to pass an argument for `UnsafeMutablePointer<AType>` or `UnsafePointer<AType>`, you usually declare a variable of type `AType` and pass it as an inout argument (specified by prefix '&').

  The parameter types of your `ListReaders` becomes `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>!` and `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt>!`, so you need to declare variables of type `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?` (== `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?`) and `UInt` (== `CUnsignedLong`).